# Keras implementation of Inception-v3 does not have the BN-Auxillary

Tags: python, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have been using the keras inception-v3 model in my experiments. However, when I print the model summary, I cannot see the BN-Auxillary layer. I am trying to understand if this a bug or been left out for a specific reason?. According to "Rethinking the Inception Architecture for Computer Vision" by Szegedy et al., the auxiliary layer adds 0.4% improvement in top-1 error and is the principle difference between inception-v2 and inception-v3. I have attached the source-code for the inception-v3 from keras library here. Any valuable insights could be useful to my experiments.

```
def InceptionV3(include_top=True,
                weights='imagenet',
                input_tensor=None,
                input_shape=None,
                pooling=None,
                classes=1000):
    """Instantiates the Inception v3 architecture.

Optionally loads weights pre-trained
on ImageNet. Note that when using TensorFlow,
for best performance you should set
`image_data_format="channels_last"` in your Keras config
at ~/.keras/keras.json.
The model and the weights are compatible with both
TensorFlow and Theano. The data format
convention used by the model is the one
specified in your Keras config file.
Note that the default input image size for this model is 299x299.

Arguments:
    include_top: whether to include the fully-connected
        layer at the top of the network.
    weights: one of `None` (random initialization)
        or "imagenet" (pre-training on ImageNet).
    input_tensor: optional Keras tensor (i.e. output of `layers.Input()`)
        to use as image input for the model.
    input_shape: optional shape tuple, only to be specified
        if `include_top` is False (otherwise the input shape
        has to be `(299, 299, 3)` (with `channels_last` data format)
        or `(3, 299, 299)` (with `channels_first` data format).
        It should have exactly 3 inputs channels,
        and width and height should be no smaller than 139.
        E.g. `(150, 150, 3)` would be one valid value.
    pooling: Optional pooling mode for feature extraction
        when `include_top` is `False`.
        - `None` means that the output of the model will be
            the 4D tensor output of the
            last convolutional layer.
        - `avg` means that global average pooling
            will be applied to the output of the
            last convolutional layer, and thus
            the output of the model will be a 2D tensor.
        - `max` means that global max pooling will
            be applied.
    classes: optional number of classes to classify images
        into, only to be specified if `include_top` is True, and
        if no `weights` argument is specified.

Returns:
    A Keras model instance.

Raises:
    ValueError: in case of invalid argument for `weights`,
        or invalid input shape.
"""
if weights not in {'imagenet', None}:
    raise ValueError('The `weights` argument should be either '
                     '`None` (random initialization) or `imagenet` '
                     '(pre-training on ImageNet).')

if weights == 'imagenet' and include_top and classes != 1000:
    raise ValueError('If using `weights` as imagenet with `include_top`'
                     ' as true, `classes` should be 1000')

# Determine proper input shape
input_shape = _obtain_input_shape(
    input_shape,
    default_size=299,
    min_size=139,
    data_format=K.image_data_format(),
    include_top=include_top)

if input_tensor is None:
    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
else:
    img_input = Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    channel_axis = 1
else:
    channel_axis = 3

x = conv2d_bn(img_input, 32, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')
x = conv2d_bn(x, 32, 3, 3, padding='valid')
x = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 3, 3)
x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

x = conv2d_bn(x, 80, 1, 1, padding='valid')
x = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 3, 3, padding='valid')
x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

# mixed 0, 1, 2: 35 x 35 x 256
branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(branch5x5, 64, 5, 5)

branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 32, 1, 1)
x = layers.concatenate(
    [branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
    axis=channel_axis,
    name='mixed0')

# mixed 1: 35 x 35 x 256
branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(branch5x5, 64, 5, 5)

branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 64, 1, 1)
x = layers.concatenate(
    [branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
    axis=channel_axis,
    name='mixed1')

# mixed 2: 35 x 35 x 256
branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
branch5x5 = conv2d_bn(branch5x5, 64, 5, 5)

branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 64, 1, 1)
x = layers.concatenate(
    [branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
    axis=channel_axis,
    name='mixed2')

# mixed 3: 17 x 17 x 768
branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 384, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')

branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(
    branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')

branch_pool = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = layers.concatenate(
    [branch3x3, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool], axis=channel_axis, name='mixed3')

# mixed 4: 17 x 17 x 768
branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)

branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(x, 128, 1, 1)
branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 128, 1, 7)
branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 192, 7, 1)

branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 128, 1, 1)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 128, 7, 1)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 128, 1, 7)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 128, 7, 1)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 1, 7)

branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 192, 1, 1)
x = layers.concatenate(
    [branch1x1, branch7x7, branch7x7dbl, branch_pool],
    axis=channel_axis,
    name='mixed4')

# mixed 5, 6: 17 x 17 x 768
for i in range(2):
    branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)

    branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(x, 160, 1, 1)
    branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 160, 1, 7)
    branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 192, 7, 1)

    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 160, 1, 1)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 160, 7, 1)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 160, 1, 7)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 160, 7, 1)
    branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 1, 7)

    branch_pool = AveragePooling2D(
        (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
    branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 192, 1, 1)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch1x1, branch7x7, branch7x7dbl, branch_pool],
        axis=channel_axis,
        name='mixed' + str(5 + i))

# mixed 7: 17 x 17 x 768
branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)

branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)
branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 192, 1, 7)
branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 192, 7, 1)

branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 7, 1)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 1, 7)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 7, 1)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 1, 7)

branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 192, 1, 1)
x = layers.concatenate(
    [branch1x1, branch7x7, branch7x7dbl, branch_pool],
    axis=channel_axis,
    name='mixed7')

# mixed 8: 8 x 8 x 1280
branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)
branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3, 320, 3, 3,
                      strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')

branch7x7x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)
branch7x7x3 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7x3, 192, 1, 7)
branch7x7x3 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7x3, 192, 7, 1)
branch7x7x3 = conv2d_bn(
    branch7x7x3, 192, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')

branch_pool = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = layers.concatenate(
    [branch3x3, branch7x7x3, branch_pool], axis=channel_axis, name='mixed8')

# mixed 9: 8 x 8 x 2048
for i in range(2):
    branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 320, 1, 1)

    branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 384, 1, 1)
    branch3x3_1 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3, 384, 1, 3)
    branch3x3_2 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3, 384, 3, 1)
    branch3x3 = layers.concatenate(
        [branch3x3_1, branch3x3_2], axis=channel_axis, name='mixed9_' + str(i))

    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 448, 1, 1)
    branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 384, 3, 3)
    branch3x3dbl_1 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 384, 1, 3)
    branch3x3dbl_2 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 384, 3, 1)
    branch3x3dbl = layers.concatenate(
        [branch3x3dbl_1, branch3x3dbl_2], axis=channel_axis)

    branch_pool = AveragePooling2D(
        (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x)
    branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 192, 1, 1)
    x = layers.concatenate(
        [branch1x1, branch3x3, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
        axis=channel_axis,
        name='mixed' + str(9 + i))
if include_top:
    # Classification block
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
    x = Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
else:
    if pooling == 'avg':
        x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    elif pooling == 'max':
        x = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)

# Ensure that the model takes into account
# any potential predecessors of `input_tensor`.
if input_tensor is not None:
    inputs = get_source_inputs(input_tensor)
else:
    inputs = img_input
# Create model.
model = Model(inputs, x, name='inception_v3')

# load weights
if weights == 'imagenet':
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
            warnings.warn('You are using the TensorFlow backend, yet you '
                          'are using the Theano '
                          'image data format convention '
                          '(`image_data_format="channels_first"`). '
                          'For best performance, set '
                          '`image_data_format="channels_last"` in '
                          'your Keras config '
                          'at ~/.keras/keras.json.')
    if include_top:
        weights_path = get_file(
            'inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5',
            WEIGHTS_PATH,
            cache_subdir='models',
            md5_hash='9a0d58056eeedaa3f26cb7ebd46da564')
    else:
        weights_path = get_file(
            'inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5',
            WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP,
            cache_subdir='models',
            md5_hash='bcbd6486424b2319ff4ef7d526e38f63')
    model.load_weights(weights_path)
    if K.backend() == 'theano':
        convert_all_kernels_in_model(model)
return model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Batch Normalized Auxiliary layers were introduced as a part of Inception-v3 architecture to mitigate the problems that arise due to having deep convolutional layers stacked upon one another. Compared to the tensor-flow version, the Inception-v3 in Keras is a pre-trained model without the auxiliary layers. It may be left out since the Inception-v3 in Keras was meant to be used as a plug and play with model weights for direct prediction tasks (application). Link: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/inception_v3.py

The model in Keras can be retrained but will not give the same results as reported by the original paper.